# Matrix Multiplication on Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a affine/projective variety on field $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. And let $M$ be a full-rank matrix from $\mathbb{C}^m\to\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively. Then I know that automorphism of projective space $\mathbb{CP}^m$ or $\mathbb{RP}^m$ is projective linear group.

But my question is :

Does $M$ preserve variety structure? If not, what are the conditions that a matrix can be a morphism between varieties?

I cannot find any references about this question, neither can I solve this question by myself, as I am a learning student.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with preserve variety structure ? $x \mapsto Mx$ is a morphism of affine space and it sends $V(I)$ to (a dense subset of) $V(J), J=\{ g \in K[Y], g(MX) \in I\}$. When $M$ is surjective let $S= \{ h(MY), h \in I, h(X)=h(M^*(MM^*)^{-1} MX)\}$  then $J = (S)$

Comment: If $\varphi: \mathbb C^m \to \mathbb C^n$ is any polynomial map, then $\varphi$ sends Zariski closed sets to constructible sets by Chevalley's theorem.